# I am getting error while building aws cdk rds **Stack failed: ValidationError: Given input did not match expected format

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I am getting error while building rds instance using typescript langauge:
Error :
Argument of type '{ engine: DatabaseInstanceEngine; vpc: Vpc; vpcPlacement: { subnetType: SubnetType.ISOLATED; }; storageEncrypted: true; multiAz: false; autoMinorVersionUpgrade: false; ... 8 more ...; port: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DatabaseInstanceProps'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'instanceClass' does not exist in type 'DatabaseInstanceProps'.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L005A.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using a mistyped attribute. Try and replace the attribute `instanceClass` in your database instance properties with `instanceType`.

Here’s the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-rds.DatabaseInstanceProps.html) for your reference.

Comment: worked !!! Thanks @Dennis but after building and while deploying it is giving me error as:  RDSStack failed: ValidationError: Given input did not match expected format
Given input did not match expected format

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur and what have you tried to fix it? And please accept my answer if it solved your original question.

Comment: I just changed intanceclass with instancetype. I have accepted the answer but since i donot have enough badges so it is still under review.

Comment: I am able to build them successfully but unable to synth(cdk synth RDSStack). I tried to add one more variable to it but same result.